# Loading properties file from yml as Factory Bean in JUNIT

Tags: java, spring, junit

I have list of properties in my yml for eachplatform tv and android

i have created one factory class where we provide the platform and you will get the properties  , using the referring link "https://andrewzc.com/loading-configuration-properties-in-spring-boot-test/" . 
    but on running the test the property object is coming as null . How to load properties in junit from properties file ?

```
@Component
public class MasterPropertiesFactory {

   @Autowired
    private TvProperties  tv ;

    @Autowired
    private AndroidProperties android ;


    public MasterPropertiesClass getProperty(String platform){
             if(platform.equals("tv")){
            return  tv;
        }else if(platform.equals("android")){
            return  android;
        }


    }

}
```

Now i am writing a junit to read these properties but on running test getPaginatedContent it is coming as null .

//PageTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApp.class ,MasterPropertiesFactory.class }, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
class PageTest {

    @Autowired
    MasterPropertiesFactory masterPropertiesFactory;


    @Test
    void getPaginatedContent() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(masterPropertiesFactory);
    }




}

// TestApp.java

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(value = {MasterPropertiesFactory.class })
public class TestApp {}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're several points you should fix in your code:

1. There should be `Configuration` class for creating `TvProperties` and `AndroidProperties`
2. Either you should use that class in `PageTest` - `ContextConfiguration`or you should declare custom `Configuration` class for the test, to load the properties.
3. `@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestApp.class ,MasterPropertiesFactory.class }`is not good idea, because, it should contain information about `Configuration` classes.
4. For `@Autowired
   MasterPropertiesFactory masterPropertiesFactory;` somewhere you should create bean for that (preferred way is in test `Conifugration`)